# Merge Data from multiple API Endpoints into one Database

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, api

I am currently building a table that stores data it receives from an api endpoint via url. I want to add additional columns from a different endpoint. The Data is stored in JSON format and the two datasets have one key in common that is the item name.

I cant think of a way to merge these two datasets by their related key. I just started coding like a month ago. Do I need to build a database that stores the data or can i do it with php? I expirimented with mySQL but i couldent find a way to load the data from the url into my database.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So i pretent to have the following data in base.json

```
[{ "id": 4, "name": "james" }, { "id": 6, "name": "tim" }]
```

and in 2nd.json

```
{ "4": ["flower", "car"], "6": ["house", "server"] }
```

so now the following PHP-Code will merge them

```
<?php

$api_endpoint = json_decode(file_get_contents('base.json'), true);
$additional = json_decode(file_get_contents('2nd.json'), true);
$merged_data = array();

foreach ($api_endpoint as $data) {
    $merged_data[] = array_merge($data, $additional[$data['id']]);
}

var_dump($merged_data);
```

The Result would look like this:

```
["0"] => Array(
    ["id"] => int(4)
    ["name"] => str("james")
    ["0"] => str("flower")
    ["1"] => str("car")
)
["1"] => Array(
    ["id"] => int(6)
    ["name"] => str("tim")
    ["0"] => str("house")
    ["1"] => str("server")
)
```

So now you could use the `$merged_data` and insert it into your database.